# Ansible - Is it possible to run or merge two different inventories within the tasks/playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am running a playbook with the command

`ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -i /roles/test/vars/inventory/configuration.yml`

At the moment, is running a "custom" inventory I've created like so:

```
-----configuration.yml-----

 virtual_servers:
   hosts:
       test1.local:
         name: "test-1.local"
         type: "standard"
         vs_port: 443
         description: ""
         monitor_interval: 30
         ssl_flag: true
         ...
(omissis)

-----playbook snippet-----
- name: "Verify data"
  import_role:
    name: test_role
    tasks_from: verify_data
  delegate_to: localhost
```

And I'm running various tasks, among which I have to "jump" to another host, to perform the actual configuration edit (we are talking about F5 load balancers, if it helps) and the inventory defines the parameters and variables for the creation.
This is an example:

```
- name: Get failover state
  f5networks.f5_modules.bigip_device_info:
    gather_subset:
      - devices
    provider:
      server: "{{ item }}"
      user: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
  with_items: groups[target_devices]
```

It looks like whenever I run this task the `target_devices` aren't in the inventory, because they are not defined within the `configuration.yml` file.

Now, my question is: is it possible to run this task with a different inventory subset, by adding it in some way or merging it to the `configuration.yml`? I thought that delegation would work in this case, but I can't figure a way out.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

It seems that the inventory which I called was a malformed YAML file, so I created a new one with the correct syntax, to avoid modifying it in production.

I found out two ways to simultaneously use the 2 different inventory files:

1. Create or import the YAML files within a single folder, and pass it
   to the `-i` parameter when running the playbook. Be aware that in other configurations, this might be a problem because of unused files. For example :

`ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -i /roles/test/vars/inventory`

2. Run multiple `-i` parameters, like the following:

`ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml -i /roles/test/vars/inventory/configuration.yml -i /roles/test/vars/inventory/other_inventory.yml`

Comment: Fails with Ansible 2.3, need to use jq.